For what values of $a$ is the integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^a}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}$ convergent?
For what values of $a$ is the integral $$\int_1^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$ convergent?
I'm seeking not only a solution but also some intuition behind problems of this nature.
The constant $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ doesn't matter (it cannot alter the convergence).
I've already reasoned that $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$ (so when $a=1$) diverges as I've noted that for $x > e$, $\frac{1}{x} < \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$, implying the divergence (as $\int\dfrac{1}{x}dx$ diverges).
However, I'm unsure how to approach $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2}dx$ and how this relates to determining the range of $a$ for convergence. How can I establish that $a$ should be greater than $1$ intuitively?
What's wrong with $a=\frac12$ for example? $\sqrt{x}$ still goes faster to infinity than $\ln(x)$.
I have seen these questions and they do not help me understand what's going on.
Parametric improper integrals
Does $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{x^2} dx $ converge or diverge?

The idea behind limit test is the following, since

for $a>1$

$$\frac{\frac{\ln x}{x^a}}{\frac1{x^{\frac {1+a}2}}}=\frac{\ln x}{x^{\frac {a-1}2}} \to 0$$
by definition, eventually
$$0\le \frac{\ln x}{x^a} \le \frac1{x^{\frac {1+a}2}}$$
which leads to convergence by comparison test, while

for $0<a\le 1$

$$\frac{\frac{\ln x}{x^a}}{\frac1{x}}=x^{1-a}\ln x \to \infty$$
by definition, eventually
$$ \frac{\ln(x)}{x^a} \ge \frac1{x}$$
which leads to divergence by comparison test.

may i ask you where did $x^\frac{1+a}{2}$ come in the denominator?

@MathStudent This is a trick, in this way we have that $1<\frac{1+a}{2}<a$

I see it really works well, but I am not really sure I understand the intuition behind it. How is this inequality useful? Knowing that we would have to subtract $\frac{1+a}{2}$ from $a$, or that's not what's leading? Thanks!

in this way we have that $\frac{\frac{\ln x}{x^a}}{\frac1{x^{\frac {1+a}2}}}\to 0$ and that $\frac1{x^{\frac {1+a}2}}$ converges

If $a<1$ then $x^{a}<x$, or equivalently, $\dfrac{1}{x^a}>\dfrac{1}{x}$, for every $x>1$.
Using that $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx$ diverges, which you have already proved, we get $$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}\,dx>\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx=+\infty$$
which implies that $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}\,dx$ diverges too.
To prove the convergence for $a>1$, you can use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^\alpha}=0$ for every $\alpha>0$ (that is, the logarithm is eventually smaller than every power function).

For any $a>1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
   \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^a}dx & =\frac1{1-a}\int_1^\infty \ln x~d\frac1{x^{a-1}} \\
   & =\left.\frac{\ln x}{(1-a)x^{a-1}}\right|_1^\infty+\frac1{a-1}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^a} \\
   & =\frac1{(a-1)^2} \\
   & <\infty.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Therefore the integral always converges for any $a>1$.
